# Issue with AsyncStorage and Asynchronous Behavior in React Native Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, asyncstorage

I'm encountering an issue related to asynchronous behavior in my React Native functional component that involves the use of `AsyncStorage`. I have a custom component for AsyncStorage operations, and I've also tried using `AsyncStorage` directly, but the problem persists.

**Code:**

I have a React Native functional component named `EntryScreen`, and I'm using `AsyncStorage` for handling user data. The component involves various asynchronous operations, including data retrieval and synchronization with Firebase.

```
/* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-shadow */
/* eslint-disable react-native/no-inline-styles */
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  SafeAreaView,
  Modal,
  View,
  TextInput,
  FlatList,
  Alert,
} from 'react-native';
import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import DatePicker from 'react-native-date-picker';
import {Image, Switch} from '@rneui/base';
import {ScheduleNotification} from '../../utils/Notification/notification';
import {Dropdown} from 'react-native-element-dropdown';
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';
import styles from './styles';
import NotificationChannels from '../../utils/Notification/NotificationChannels';
import State from '../../../Store';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import CreateUserDB from '../../utils/db/CreateUserDB';
import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';
const EntryScreen = ({navigation}: any) => {
  // user var which comes from Async Storage
  const [user, setUser] = useState<any>();
  const modal = State.useState(state => state.alarmModal);
  const [date, setDate] = useState<number>(Date.now());
  const snooze = State.useState(state => state.snooze);
  const [alarmLabel, setAlarmLabel] = useState<string>('');
  const [data, setData] = useState<any>([]);
  const [updateId, setUpdateId] = useState<number>(0);
  const [channel, setChannel] = useState<string>('');
  const db = CreateUserDB(user?.username);

  useEffect(() => {
    initializeData();
    NotificationChannels.alarms_carpark();
    NotificationChannels.alarms_sneez();
    NotificationChannels.alarms_synth();
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    db.createTable();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    db.getData(dataArr => setData(dataArr));
  }, [data]);

  useEffect(() => {
    PushNotification.localNotification({
      title: 'hello',
      message: 'hello',
      channelId: 'alarms_sneez',
    });
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    const autoSyncFirebase = async () => {
      const userRef = database().ref(
        user?.authType === 'email' ? `/${user.username}` : `/${user.id}`,
      );

      await Promise.all(
        data.map(async (element: any) => {
          await db.deleteElement(element.id);
        }),
      );

      const snapshot = await userRef.once('value');
      const fbData = snapshot.val().data;

      await Promise.all(
        fbData.map(async (element: any) => {
          await db.setData(
            element.timestamp,
            element.title,
            element.isNotificationOn,
            element.isSnooze,
          );
        }),
      );
    };

    autoSyncFirebase();
  }, []);

  const initializeData = async () => {
    const retrievedUser = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
    if (retrievedUser) {
      setUser(JSON.parse(retrievedUser));
    }
  };

  const handleOnListPress = (item: any) => {
    State.update(state => {
      state.alarmModal = true;
    });
    setUpdateId(item.id);
    setDate(item.timestamp);
    setAlarmLabel(item.title);
  };

  const onCancelPress = () => {
    State.update(state => {
      state.alarmModal = false;
    });
    setDate(Date.now());
    setUpdateId(0);
    State.update(state => {
      state.snooze = false;
    });
  };

  const onSavePress = () => {
    const isNewAlarm = updateId === 0;
    isNewAlarm
      ? db.setData(date, alarmLabel, true, snooze)
      : db.updateAlarm(date, alarmLabel, snooze, updateId);

    setDate(Date.now());
    State.update(state => {
      state.alarmModal = false;
      state.snooze = false;
    });

    ScheduleNotification(new Date(date), alarmLabel, snooze, channel);
  };

  const onDeleteAlarmPress = () => {
    db.deleteElement(updateId);
    State.update(state => {
      state.alarmModal = false;
    });
    setUpdateId(0);
  };

  const firebaseSync = async () => {
    const userRef = await database().ref(
      user.authType === 'email' ? `/${user.username}` : `/${user.id}`,
    );
    if (data > 0) {
      userRef.update({data: data});
    } else {
      function syncFromFirebase() {
        data.forEach((element: any) => {
          db.deleteElement(element.id);
        });
        userRef.once('value').then(snapshot => {
          const fbData = snapshot.val().data;
          fbData.forEach((element: any) => {
            db.setData(
              element.timestamp,
              element.title,
              element.isNotificationOn,
              element.isSnooze,
            );
          });
        });
      }
      function syncData() {
        userRef.update({data: data});
      }
      Alert.alert('WARNING', 'DO YOU WANNA SYNC EMPTY DATA?', [
        {text: 'get synced data', onPress: syncFromFirebase},
        {text: 'sync data', onPress: syncData},
      ]);
    }
  };
  const renderItem = ({item}: any) => {
    const dateString = new Date(item.timestamp).toLocaleTimeString([], {
      hour12: true,
      hour: '2-digit',
      minute: '2-digit',
    });

    const handleSwitchToggle = (value: boolean, item: any) => {
      if (value) {
        db.updateNotificationValue(true, item.id);
        ScheduleNotification(
          new Date(item.timestamp),
          item.title,
          item.isSnooze,
          channel,
        );
      } else {
        db.updateNotificationValue(false, item.id);
        PushNotification.getScheduledLocalNotifications(list => {
          list.forEach(notification => {
            const itemTimestamp = new Date(item.timestamp).toLocaleTimeString(
              [],
              {hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', hour12: true},
            );
            const notificationTimestamp = notification.date.toLocaleTimeString(
              [],
              {hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', hour12: true},
            );

            if (itemTimestamp === notificationTimestamp) {
              PushNotification.cancelLocalNotification(notification.id);
            }
          });
        });
      }
    };

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => handleOnListPress(item)}
        style={[styles.listViewStyles]}>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.mainDateString}>{dateString}</Text>
          <Text>{item.title}, Every Wednesday</Text>
        </View>
        <Switch
          value={!!item.isNotificationOn}
          onValueChange={value => handleSwitchToggle(value, item)}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <View style={styles.topBarInnerContainer}>
        <MaterialIcons
          name="sync"
          size={30}
          color={'white'}
          onPress={firebaseSync}
          style={styles.syncBtn}
        />

        <Image
          source={
            user?.photo
              ? {uri: user?.photo}
              : require('../../assets/images/google.png')
          }
          style={styles.profileImg}
          resizeMode="contain"
          onPress={() => {
            navigation.navigate('profile');
          }}
        />
      </View>

      <View style={styles.topBarContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.headerFont}>Alarms</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.plusBtn}
          onPress={() =>
            State.update(state => {
              state.alarmModal = true;
            })
          }>
          <AntDesign name="plus" size={40} color={'orange'} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <FlatList
        keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        data={data}
      />

      <Modal visible={modal} transparent={false} animationType="slide">
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.modalContainer}>
          <View style={styles.modalTopBar}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.modalTopBtn}
              onPress={onCancelPress}>
              <Text style={styles.modalTopBtnText}>Cancel</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 20}}>Set Timer</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.modalTopBtn} onPress={onSavePress}>
              <Text style={styles.modalTopBtnText}>
                {updateId === 0 ? 'Save' : 'Update'}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.modalInnerContainer}>
            <DatePicker
              date={new Date(date)}
              onDateChange={date => setDate(date.getTime())}
              mode="time"
              style={styles.datePickerStyles}
              is24hourSource="locale"
            />
            <View style={styles.bottomContainerMain}>
              <View style={styles.modalBottomContainerItem}>
                <Text style={styles.modalBottomContainerLabel}>Repeat</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.neverBtn}>
                  <Text style={{fontSize: 18}}>Never</Text>
                  <AntDesign name="right" size={20} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.modalBottomContainerItem}>
                <Text style={styles.modalBottomContainerLabel}>Label</Text>
                <TextInput
                  placeholder="Hello there"
                  value={alarmLabel}
                  onChangeText={val => setAlarmLabel(val)}
                />
              </View>
              <View style={styles.modalBottomContainerItem}>
                <Text style={[styles.modalBottomContainerLabel, {flex: 2}]}>
                  Sound
                </Text>
                <Dropdown
                  labelField={'label'}
                  data={[
                    {value: 1, label: 'alarm_carpark'},
                    {value: 2, label: 'alarm_sneez'},
                    {value: 3, label: 'alarm_synth'},
                  ]}
                  valueField={'value'}
                  placeholder={channel}
                  value={channel}
                  onChange={item => setChannel(item.label)}
                  style={styles.dropDownStyles}
                />
              </View>
              <View style={styles.modalBottomContainerItem}>
                <Text style={styles.modalBottomContainerLabel}>Snooze</Text>
                <Switch
                  color="green"
                  value={snooze}
                  onValueChange={() => {
                    State.update(state => {
                      state.snooze = !state.snooze;
                    });
                  }}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
            {updateId !== 0 && (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={onDeleteAlarmPress}
                style={styles.deleteAlarmBtn}>
                <Text style={styles.deleteAlarmBtnText}>Delete Alarm</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
          </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </Modal>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.logOutBtn}
        onPress={async () => {
          await AsyncStorage.removeItem('user')
            .then(() => {
              data.forEach((element: any) => db.deleteElement(element.id));
              console.log('success');
              navigation.navigate('signup');
              setData(undefined);
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
        }}>
        <Text style={styles.logOutBtnText}>Log out</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default EntryScreen;
```

```
export const getAsyncVar = async (key: string) => {
  try {
    const response = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
    if (typeof response === 'object') {
      if (response) {
        return JSON.parse(response);
      }
    } else {
      return response;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  return null;
};

export const getAllAsyncVars = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
    if (response) {
      return response;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  return null;
};
```

**Issues:**

- I'm encountering the error "Possible unhandled promise rejection: cannot read property 'id' of undefined." in the `renderItem` function.
- There seems to be an issue with the asynchronous behavior of the `autoSyncFirebase` function.

**Specific Questions:**

1. How can I handle the "Possible unhandled promise rejection" error in the `renderItem` function?
2. Are there any improvements needed in the `autoSyncFirebase` function to ensure proper asynchronous behavior?

I appreciate any guidance or suggestions on resolving these issues. Thank you!

---